# The parameters (DocumentApp.ListItem) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.Body.appendParagraph

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Trying to connect a google spreadsheet and a google document together in google script and I am on what I have done wrong.
error messages:

> (anonymous)@Code.gs:12
> myFunction@Code.gs:11

```
function myFunction() {

  var docTemplateId = "144IYPXNG2Yqb2XqQCv91CUpQ8NMoaZrwBtq-pW-NaQM";
  var docFinalId = "1vXZn6NVwI2ee5RzCLvJCL6nXWSWdcKMZ9uzvBjtyRzY";
  var wsId = "1-4aGpNWi2gtVw2kIjKM7B5tRTQhrT-eoSRxBr5K_AIk";

  var docTemplate = DocumentApp.openById(docTemplateId);
  var docFinal = DocumentApp.openById(docFinalId);
  
  var templateParagraphs = docTemplate.getBody().getParagraphs();
  templateParagraphs.forEach(function(p){
    docFinal.getBody().appendParagraph(p.copy().replaceText("{ID}", "I"));

  });
}
```

Comment: Where's the spreadsheet in your code?

Comment: @Cooper I haven't fully completed it but I tried running this just in case I got an error. What I wanted to do was connect my template to create a separate google doc and fill things into the doc every time something was added to the spreadsheet automatically. But, this is just the start of it and I was just a bit confused on why it gave this error

Comment: Because replaceText() returns and element not a paragraph.  [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph) I believe if you add .asParagraph() it will work as expected.  It's like a casting operation. [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#asParagraph())

Answer (score 1):

After

```
var docFinal = DocumentApp.openById(docFinalId);
```

add

```
var body = docFinal.getBody();
```

then replace

```
docFinal.getBody().appendParagraph(p.copy().replaceText("{ID}", "I"));
```

by

```
 var q = body.appendParagraph(p.copy());
 q.replaceText("{ID}", "I");
```

Comment: @Cooper I used something very similar few moments before posting this answer, but instead of a Paragraph and append I  used a TableRow and insert. While q.repalceText() still returns an element, it isn't used as parameter of appendParagraph.